# Navigation using Drawer with nested routes

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have the following structure inside my main screen:

```
DrawerNavigator
  drawer with a list of screens to navigate
  Drawer.Screen
    MaterialTopTabNavigator
      TopTab.Screen
      TopTab.Screen
      TopTab.Screen
```

I need when I click at an item inside the drawer, navigate to a new rote without the drawer, what's the best approach to do it?
I tried with a StackNavigator inside the Drawer to prevent the error of the navigate without an handled navigator not found, but it's navigate with the drawer presents.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with changes on the navigation level:

```
Stack Navigator   
  DrawerNavigator
    drawer with a list of screens to navigate
    Drawer.Screen
      MaterialTopTabNavigator
        TopTab.Screen
        TopTab.Screen
        TopTab.Screen   
  Stack.Screen (the screens on the drawer that I want to navigate)
```

Special thanks to expo discord community! Hope this helps someone with the same problem.